# escaping quotes inside quotes

Tags: arrays, preg-replace

I have some malformed json, I need to fix (I can't fix the source)

`...
    "productName": "Widget "Foo"",
    "productVariation": "",
...`

It should be

`...
    "productName": "Widget \"Foo\"",
    "productVariation": "",
...`

It appears I can with a preg find what's inside the quotes.

```
/productName":\s*"(.*?)",\s*"productVariation/
```

I have fixed other json-errors woth preg_replace, but I cannot figure out how to escape quotes inside the match.

Answer (score 0):

It helps talking to the teddybear...

```
$s = preg_replace_callback('/(productName":\s*")(.*?)(",\s*"productVariation)/',
    function ($matches) {
        return $matches[1].addslashes($matches[2]).$matches[3];
    },$s);
```